# fcgi, ssl and django, redirect HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: django, redirect, https, lighttpd, fastcgi

I have a django site setup with lighttpd and ssl working but I can not seem to get a redirect to work from http to https. My setup is very similar to: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/fastcgi/#lighttpd-setup and I'm using lighttpd/1.4.26 on ubuntu

Basically my setup looks something like this:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "myhost.com" {
server.document-root = "/home/myvenv/blah" 
fastcgi.server = ( 
    "/blah.fcgi" => (
    (   
        "host" => "127.0.0.1",
        "port" => 16666,
        "check-local" => "disable",
        "max-procs" => 4,
        "min-procs" => 4,
    )   
)   
)
   url.rewrite-once = ( 
    "^(/favicon.ico.*)$" => "/$1",
    "^(/admin_media.*)$" => "/$1",
    "^(/media.*)$" => "/$1",
    "^(/.*)$" => "/blah.fcgi$1",
)

expire.url = ( 
    "/favicon.ico" => "access 1 seconds",
    "/admin_media" => "access 1 seconds",
"/media" => "access 1 seconds",
)

}
```

I want to add this to do my http to https redirect:

```
$SERVER["socket"] == ":80" {
  $HTTP["host"] =~ "(.*)" {
    url.redirect = ( "^/(.*)" => "https://%1/$1" )
  }
}
```

The problem is when I enable the redirect, my url gets rewritten like:

https://myhost.com/blah.fcgi/my/path/to/blah

putting in the blah.fcgi part when I really just want:

https://myhost.com/my/path/to/blah

I'm not sure why the redirect includes the rewrite and/or how to prevent it and actually do the correct redirection?

Much thanks in adavance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use lighttpd in the same fashion, and here is how I do a similar redirect:

```
url.redirect = (
  "^(?:/[a-z]+\.fcgi)?(.*)$" => "https://%1$1"
)
```

This removes the rewritten script name from the match on the left hand side, so it doesn't show up in the redirect.

Comment: Any idea why this happens?  I'm assuming it is because the mod_rewrite must occur before a redirect?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, I've got the same hypothesis as you though.